# Start jquery pluggin

Tags: jquery

how to achieve this with jquery plugin system

```
 $('.selector').myPlugin(function(id){
     alert(id);
 });
```

How to code *myPlugin* plugin to make it work exactly like the code above.

That's all, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can define `myPlugin` function like this:

```js
$.fn.myPlugin = function (callback) {
  var id = $(this).prop('id');

  if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback(id);
  }
};

$('.selector').myPlugin(function(id){
   alert(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="greeting" class="selector">Greeting!</div>
```

Comment: Beware of unexpected results if there are multiple elements on the page with the `selector` class (ie you'll always get the first id)

Answer (score 0):

you can not get id from anonymous function as argument.

```js
//create myPlugin function for manage your plugin
function myPlugin(id){
    alert(id);
    //enter your code here
}

$('.selector').on('click', function(){
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    myPlugin(id);
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My plugin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary selector" id="YourId" >Click me</button>
  </body>  
</html>
```

Try this script.

Comment: The OP is attempting to write their own plugin, see the other answers for examples of what the OP was after

Answer (score -1):

You would use the jQuery prototype [`$.fn`](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) to do that, here is an example. Note that i've set this up to return an array of ids because you show attaching this to a class which means that it may in fact be linked to multiple elements on the page

```js
$.fn.myPlugin = function(callback) {
  var ids = [];
  if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    $(this).each(function() {
            ids.push(this.id);
    });
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    callback(ids);
  }
};


$(function() {

  $('.selector').myPlugin(function(ids) {
    console.log(ids);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector" id="someId1">
</div>
<div class="selector" id="someId2">
</div>
```